# Ajax Post Troubleshoot

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am using ajax to post a form to my localproxy which then posts to affiliate client and also my database.  However it keeps either not posting using ajax or coming up with an error.  I used this exact code format on other sites without a problem.

my ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     // ajax code start
    $('#form').on('submit', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/localProxy.php",
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
            document.location = '/thank-you';
             // do something!
    },
    error: function () {
            alert('There was a problem!');  // handle error
    }
        });
        });
```

And here is my current form header and submit code

```
<form id="form" name="form" >

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enter" />
```

Either the default submit activates bypassing the ajax or the alert message comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have no error in your `localProxy` script or it does exist. I also noticed you have a missing function enclosure in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     // ajax code start
    $('#form').on('submit', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/localProxy.php",
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                    document.location = '/thank-you';
                     // do something!
            },
            error: function () {
                    alert('There was a problem!');  // handle error
            }
        });
    }); // <--- I just added this and it's submitting properly
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 // ajax code start
$('#form').on('submit', function (e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.post('/localProxy.php', $('#form').serialize(),
      success: function (response) {
        document.location = '/thank-you';
         // do something!
      },
      error: function () {
         alert('There was a problem!');  // handle error
      });
   });
});
```

try with this. this is shorthand version of ajax call. bt im nt sure this is OK or NT.